# Apache 2.4 mod_auth_form missing

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Centos 7. Now I'd need the [**mod_auth_form**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html) module, since the Directive **AuthFormLogoutLocation** cannot be found.
Now it's neither installed nor can I find it in the **yum search mod_auth** list:

```
$ locate modules/mod_auth
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_digest.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_anon.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_core.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authn_socache.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_core.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_owner.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so

$ yum search mod_auth
...
===== N/S matched: mod_auth ======
ipsilon-authgssapi.noarch : mod_auth_gssapi based login plugin
mod_auth_gssapi.x86_64 : A GSSAPI Authentication module for Apache
mod_auth_kerb.x86_64 : Kerberos authentication module for HTTP
mod_auth_mellon.x86_64 : A SAML 2.0 authentication module for the Apache Httpd Server
mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.x86_64 : NTLM authentication for the Apache web server using winbind daemon
mod_auth_openid.x86_64 : OpenID authentication for apache
mod_authnz_external.x86_64 : An Apache module used for authentication
mod_authnz_pam.x86_64 : PAM authorization checker and PAM Basic Authentication provider
pwauth.x86_64 : External plugin for mod_authnz_external authenticator
```

Any idea where else I can search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem been searching it for a long time
turns out that you need to install it.

I'm using apache 2.4.5 on CentOS7, do:

```
yum install mod_session
yum install mod_form
```

Then reboot the server, you'll see the `mod_auth_form.so`, `mod_session.so` (and cookie) in your apache module directory.

Comment: Thanks chaps, this was the exact solution.

Comment: @lev: Just to clarify (since I was also confused when I needed to solve this issue), only mod_session is needed. 


The mod_session rpm contains mod_auth_form.so and mod_session.so.  The mod_form rpm is something different.  From the rpm's info, it is "Utility to decode data submitted from Web forms."  It doesn't have anything to do with mod_auth_form, aside from a similar name.

Comment: And on some platforms, including some driven by EasyApache, if you install mod_session, you get mod_form automatically (it's not listed separately in the package repositories)